# How can I scrape multiple website html tables to a single excel file?

Tags: php, html, regex, web-crawler, export-to-excel

I have a list of urls I would like to scrape into *.txt format. Can anyone suggest to me how I can write a php code integrating regex and scraping all the html tables form the listed url to one excel file. I have tried doing this manually but since the urls are large in number its costing me a lot of time.

For the manual scraping I have copied the html code to notepad and saved as a html file and dragged and dropped the file to excel giving me a excel file I want.

Please send in your replies and provide the correct code to do so.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online that will guide you to do this. If you have trouble implementing the code, post here. This isn't a code writing site.

Comment: thank you, but as i have said i have trouble because i need to work on a lot of urls. So if anyone can suggest me a code that will copy the html code to the notepad, then it could well be my solution.

Comment: What have you already tried to implement? How did your attempts work differently to what you want? Like Fareesh said, we're not going to suggest or give you any code.

Comment: it this a let-all-parse-html saturday?? lol this is the fourth question that i've seen today xD

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look into the importHTML() function of [Google Spreadsheets](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507) - once imported you then have a URL which you can download as CSV (or other formats) and manipulate pretty much anyway you want to